# Mongodb: How to auto restart on crashes?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 & Mongodb 3.2.22.

Now, I want to make sure that it'll be always up and running (if it crashes - auto restart).

I searched for a solution and noticed that some people uses `respawn` on a file named `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`. The thing is, I don't have this file.

Currently when I want to restart I use `sudo service mongod restart`.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: you can use systemd instead of init.d as it has a property called restart onfailure

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: If your `mongod` instance crashes, typically this is a scenario where you want either want automatic failover (via a replica set deployment) or manual intervention to investigate and fix the issue. The only general exception might be a development or staging environment where your data is non-critical or can be restored from another source. However, automatic restart can still be unhealthy depending on the reason the process terminated. For more details see my answer on Server Fault: [Why doesn't MongoDB automatically restart?](https://serverfault.com/a/905110/129454).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have set it up via apt, then the systemd service file should be at /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mongodb.service.
Under ther service tab in the file, add "Restart=always" and do a systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: I don't have this file on the path you mentioned. But I found this file /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service . Is it the same? Should I copy that to etc?